# Working with multiple arraylists in different classes

Tags: java

Right, I'm trying to read a file and have that data stored in a arraylist(*primaryList* in **primaryList.class**). The data is just lines of countries, cities and their population. Heres an example: *USA;Chicago=2695000;*

After the data is stored, I have methods called *setPopulation* and *getPopulation* in a second class(**secondaryList.java**) that seperate the population number and store it in its own arraylist, namely *secondaryList* in **secondaryList.java**.

Everything works fine if the arraylists are in the same class. But when I separate the lists, the *primaryList* gets emptied at one point. I've been reading around and there seems to be an issue with how I'm calling the constructors if I got it right, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it in my code.

**Main.java** - class that runs the methods from other two classes

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    primaryList primaryList = new primaryList();
    secondaryList secondaryList = new secondaryList();

    primaryList.ReadFile();

    secondaryList.setPopulation(0);

    String country = secondaryList.getPopulation(0);

    System.out.println(country);
}}
```

**secondaryList.java** - class responsible for extracting the population part of the string and storing it in *secondaryList*

```
public class secondaryList {
primaryList primaryList = new primaryList();

private String country;
private ArrayList<String> secondaryList;

public secondaryList() {
    secondaryList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void setPopulation(int i) {
    System.out.println("starting setPopulation");

    int listSize = primaryList.GetInputListSize();
    System.out.println("primaryList size is: " + listSize);

    country = primaryList.GetInputList(i);

    System.out.println("setPopulation got:" + country);
    String resultPopulation = country.substring(country.indexOf("=") + 1);

    secondaryList.add(resultPopulation);
}

public String getPopulation(int i) {

    country = secondaryList.get(i);

    return country;
}}
```

**primaryList.java** - Class that reads the file and is responsible for storing it's contents in the *primaryList* list.

```
public class primaryList {

private List<String> primaryList; // List for entire row
private String country;

public primaryList() {
    primaryList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void ReadFile() throws IOException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("FileToRead.txt");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

    // Read file FileToRead.txt and add to countries list
    while ((country = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        SetInputList(country);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    System.out.println(primaryList.size());
}

public String GetInputList(int i) {
    country = primaryList.get(i);

    return country;
}

public void SetInputList(String country) {
    primaryList.add(country);
}

public int GetInputListSize() {
    int i = 0;

    i = primaryList.size();

    return i;
}}
```

**Output:** When I run the program, I get the following output:

```
primaryList size is: 11
starting setPopulation
primaryList size is: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at testing.primaryList.GetInputList(primaryList.java:32)
    at testing.secondaryList.setPopulation(secondaryList.java:22)
    at testing.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Notice how after I try to get the size of the *primaryList* from **primaryList.java** by calling it from *secondaryList*, the list is empty.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In your `SecondaryList` class, you're creating a **new** `PrimaryList`.  It's not the same instance of `PrimaryList` that you're calling `.ReadFile()` on in your `main` method.  I'm not entirely sure what your goal here is, but the easiest way to fix this is to pass the `PrimaryList` into your constructor for `SecondayList`, and store it in `SecondaryList`'s class-level member.

Comment: Stick to the Java Naming Conventions: class names in PascalCase, variable and method names in camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new instance of `primaryList` and attempting to read from it in `secondaryList`.

```
public class secondaryList {
primaryList primaryList = new primaryList(); //New instance of primaryList

private String country;
private ArrayList<String> secondaryList;

public secondaryList() {
    secondaryList = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void setPopulation(int i) {
    System.out.println("starting setPopulation");

    int listSize = primaryList.GetInputListSize(); //Reading from new instance, size is 0
    System.out.println("primaryList size is: " + listSize);

    country = primaryList.GetInputList(i);

    System.out.println("setPopulation got:" + country);
    String resultPopulation = country.substring(country.indexOf("=") + 1);

    secondaryList.add(resultPopulation);
}
```

You must reference the `primaryList` that you stored input in, which is in your `main` method. This will require you to restructure your code a little. Try including a new argument of type `primaryList` in `setPopulation`, then pass the reference to your initial `primaryList` to it.

Comment: How would I do that? Any chance you give me a code snippet?